# Multiple ProxyPass directives for Webmin on Debian Apache Server

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy, proxypass

I am trying to achieve what is described under:

**Webmin In A Sub-Directory Via A Proxy**

on this website

[Webmin under Apache Guide](http://www.webmin.com/apache.html)

...but, with more than one webmin (all on different servers, but proxied thru the main server), arranged into folders, like:

1. www.example.com/webmin1
2. www.example.com/webmin2

and so on and so forth.

With one webmin, using a file I created called "webmin.conf" under the "/etc/apache2/conf.d" folder, I have the following code:

```
ProxyPass /webmin1/ http://internalip:10000/
ProxyPassReverse /webmin1/ http://internalip:10000/
ProxyPass /webmin2/ http://internalip2:10000/
ProxyPassReverse /webmin2/ http://internalip2:10000/
<Proxy *>
allow from all
</Proxy>
```

This only works with either **one** of these enabled, but **not both**.

Please, I'd like some insights.  I am a beginner at proxypass, and directives - only 16 years old, trying to figure this stuff out.

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: What's the failure when both are enabled?  Browser errors, or web server errors?  Anything in Apache's error log?

Comment: The failure is odd - I can only log into one of the webmins.  I should have specified.

Comment: where is the error log? perhaps there is none, if apache starts normally (which it does, when both are enabled)

Comment: Debian Apache2 errors are stored in /var/log/apache2/error_log by default, I believe.

Comment: Maybe if I put both of them in Location tags it would work?

Answer (score -1):

Ok I figured it out!

There was a setting in the webmin web server (miniserv) in miniserv.conf that was preventing me from logging in.

There were two port settings and they were set to two different things for some reason.  I fixed the setting, and we were back in business!

Thanks for the comments and help anyways, folks.